# Use of LaunchedEffect vs SideEffect in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hi guys I am learning side-effect in my project. I want to know when should I use `LaunchedEffect` and `SideEffect` in which scenario. I am adding some piece of code using both effect. Please lemme know if I am doing wrong here.

1st using LaunchedEffect, please guide me if we need effect on this function or not.

```
@Composable
fun BluetoothRequestContinue(multiplePermissionsState: MultiplePermissionsState) {
    var launchPermission by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (launchPermission) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            multiplePermissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
        }
    }
    AbcMaterialButton(
        text = stringResource(R.string.continue_text),
        spacerHeight = 10.dp
    ) {
        launchPermission = true
    }
}
```

2nd using SideEffect to open setting using intent

```
@Composable
fun OpenPermissionSetting(router: Router = get()) {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
    var launchSetting by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (launchSetting) {
        SideEffect {
            activity.startActivity(router.permission.getPermissionSettingsIntent(activity))
        }
    }
    AbcMaterialButton(
        text = stringResource(R.string.open_settings),
        spacerHeight = 10.dp
    ) {
        launchSetting = true

    }
}
```

Please let me know if we need Effect or not. Also guide me if we need different effect as well. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use an Effect?  Can't you just call `multiplePermissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()` within the `AbcMarerialButton` lambda - you just need the lambda to be invoked on a button click? You can even check the `MultiplePermissionsState::allPermissionsGranted` to know if the button should even be visible or enabled.

Comment: I am reading somewhere that whatever is not composable we need to always use side effect free. Also above function will recompose, so that's why I think to be side effect free. As what I think, but may be I am wrong. Give your guidance please

Comment: `onClick()` is an Effect. It may not be very clear from the Docs. `onClick()` is outside Composable scope.

Comment: I think 1st example will don't need side effect. But I am confused for 2nd function. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you look into the code a `onClick : () -> Unit` uses a `Modifier::pointerInput` - which is `LaunchedEffect` - so its already called outside of composition.  A button click IS A side effect (the broader term), without it a button couldn't do anything.

Comment: ok now I got it..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There difference between

```
   if (launchSetting) {
        SideEffect {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

and

```
   if (launchPermission) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            multiplePermissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
        }
    }
```

both enters recomposition when conditions are true but `LaunchedEffect` is only invoked once because its key is `Unit`. `SideEffect` is invoked on each recomposition as long as condition is true.

SideEffect function can be used for operations that should be invoked **only when a successful recomposition happens**

> Recomposition starts whenever Compose thinks that the parameters of a
> composable might have changed. Recomposition is optimistic, which
> means Compose expects to finish recomposition before the parameters
> change again. If a parameter does change before recomposition
> finishes, Compose might cancel the recomposition and restart it with
> the new parameter.
>
> When recomposition is canceled, Compose discards the UI tree from the
> recomposition. If you have any side-effects that depend on the UI
> being displayed, the side-effect will be applied even if composition
> is canceled. This can lead to inconsistent app state.
>
> Ensure that all composable functions and lambdas are idempotent and
> side-effect free to handle optimistic recomposition.

[Sample from official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#sideeffect-publish)

> To share Compose state with objects not managed by compose, use the
> SideEffect composable, as it's invoked on every successful
> recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun rememberAnalytics(user: User): FirebaseAnalytics {
    val analytics: FirebaseAnalytics = remember {
        /* ... */
    }

    // On every successful composition, update FirebaseAnalytics with
    // the userType from the current User, ensuring that future analytics
    // events have this metadata attached
    SideEffect {
        analytics.setUserProperty("userType", user.userType)
    }
    return analytics
}
```

`LaunchedEffect` is for calling a function on composition or on recomposition if keys are changed.

If you write your LaunchedEffect as

```
LaunchedEffect(key1= launchPermission) {
   if(launchPermission) {
     // Do something
  }
}
```

code block inside if will not be called in composition if key is not true but whenever it changes from false to true code block will be invoked. This is useful for one-shot operations that are not fired by user interaction directly or when an operation requires a CoroutineScope invoked after user interaction, animations or calling suspend functions such as `lazyListState.animateScrollToItem()`

Definition of concept of side-effect  from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))

> In computer science, an operation, function or expression is said to
> have a side effect if it modifies some state variable value(s) outside
> its local environment, which is to say if it has any observable effect
> other than its primary effect of returning a value to the invoker of
> the operation. Example side effects include modifying a non-local
> variable, modifying a static local variable, modifying a mutable
> argument passed by reference, performing I/O or calling other
> functions with side-effects. In the presence of side effects, a
> program's behaviour may depend on history; that is, the order of
> evaluation matters. Understanding and debugging a function with side
> effects requires knowledge about the context and its possible
> histories.

Comment: How to call another composable function from inside `LaunchedEffect`?

Comment: You generally create a flag or ui state(Loading, Success, etc.) and assign this to a mutableState inside LaunchedEffect and in @Composable scope or out of LaunchedEffect check if that flag is true or ui state to preferred one